# How to change input method in WPF?

Tags: wpf, input

I want to plug in a Spanish or German keyboard and I would like the textbox in my WPF application to recognize the German or Spanish characters.

This can be achieved by changing locale of the system through regional settings and picking up a Spanish or a German keyboard as IME. But I need to change the locale of the system programmatically rather than manually.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: What i want to do is to plug a spanish or german keyboard and would like the textbox to recognize the german or spanish characters. This can be achemieved changing locale of the system through regional settings and picking up a spanish or a german keyboard as IME. But i need to change the locale of the system programmatically rather than manually.

Comment: a really bad example of a question

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but there's a **Language** Property for TextBox.

```
<TextBox Language="{Binding}">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language.aspx

So you could bind that Property to a locale attribute in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following statement for changing the keyboard language programatically

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(this, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
                    (Or)
  InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(this, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Here you can use any language code instead of en-US

Comment: The question is 4 years old...?